# Install Intel OpenCL SDK on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opencl, intel

I'd like to ask for help on installing Intel OpenCL SDK as described here [Linux with Intel® SDK for OpenCL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/sdk-for-opencl-gsg)

I have followed those steps but then I need to run SDK installer or use this archive to run installer from which I have downloaded from [Intel® SDK for OpenCL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl/download)

> intel_sdk_for_opencl_2017_7.0.0.2568_x64

This file is not executable and I have mounted it as archive with "Archive Mounter" but executing the install I was quit.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/run/user/1000/gvfs/archive:host=file%253A%252F%252F%252Fhome%252Fubuntu%252FDownloads%252Fintel%252Fintel_sdk_for_opencl_2017_7.0.0.2568_x64/intel_sdk_for_opencl_2017_7.0.0.2568_x64$ ./install.sh 
Error: Incorrect path to setup script. Setup can not be started
if the path contains ':, ~, @, #, %, &, [, ], $, =, ), (, *' symbols.

Quitting!
```

Anyone has experience on how to install Intel OpenCL SDK under Linux (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the script is unhappy about the symbols (like %) in the working directory. Just use a file manager to copy the contents from the mounted volume to your home folder. Then launch the install from there.